# Passing a limit inside integral in the $L^{3}$ space

Tags: functional-analysis, limits

Let $g_{n} \rightarrow g$ in $L^3(\Omega), \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{d}$. Show that for any $h \in L^3(\Omega)$

$$\int_{\Omega}g_{n}^{2}h(x) dx \rightarrow \int_{\Omega}g^{2}h(x) dx$$

So far I can show that both integrals are bounded by $\|g\|_{3}^{2}\|h\|_{3}$ using Holder's inequality, but I'm not sure how to proceed from there, or if that's the right way to go about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
\begin{align*}
\left| \int_\Omega g_n^2 h(x) \, dx -\int_\Omega g(x)^2 h(x) \, dx \right| &\le \int_\Omega |g_n^2(x) -g^2(x)| h(x) \, dx \\
&= \int_\Omega |g_n(x) -g(x)| |g_n(x)+g(x)| h(x) \, dx
\end{align*}
Now apply the Hölder-inequality in order to get the bound
$$\tag{1}\|h\|_{L^3} \|g-g_n\|_{L^3} \|g+g_n\|_{L^3}.$$
We also have that $\|g_n+g\|_{L^3} \le \|g_n - g\|_{L^3} + 2\|g\|_{L^3}$ (This shows that $(g+g_n)_n$ is bounded in $L^3$, in view of $g_n \rightarrow g$ in $L^3$.) Thus (1) can be estimated by
$$\tag{2}\|h\|_{L^3} \|g_n - g\|_{L^3} (2 \|g\|_{L^3} + \|g_n-g\|_{L^3}).$$
Since $g_n \rightarrow g$ in $L^3$, the last term (2) vanishes if $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

We want to show that $$\int_\Omega (g_n^2 - g^2)h dx \to 0.$$ We can do this by writing
\begin{align*}
\int_\Omega (g_n^2 - g^2)h dx &= \int_\Omega (g_n - g)(g_n+g)h dx \\
&\leq \|g_n - g\|_{L^3} \bigg( \int_\Omega (g_n+g)^{3/2}h^{3/2} \bigg)^{2/3} \\
&\leq \|g_n - g\|_{L^3} \|g_n + g\|_{L^3} \|h\|_{L^3} \to 0
\end{align*}
where each inequality is just an application of Holder's inequality and the convergence follows since $(g_n + g)$ is bounded in $L^3$ and $g_n-g \to 0$ in $L^3$.